# use of combobox to appear another combobox C#

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I want to make this as, once i select the first item(`Student Information`) of the `first_ComboBox` want to appear `second_ComboBox`.

How can I make this happen

In the cs code

```
private void first_ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void second_ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

in XAML

```
<StackPanel Margin="97,47,171,499" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Where You want to Control" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="82" Width="463" FontSize="36"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="first_ComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="560" Height="42" SelectionChanged="first_ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
            <x:String>Student Information</x:String>
            <x:String>Staff Information</x:String>
            <x:String>Academic Information</x:String>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Margin="97,172,171,374" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Select the Field" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="82" Width="463" FontSize="36"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="second_ComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="560" Height="42" SelectionChanged="second_ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
            <x:String>Student Name</x:String>
            <x:String>Student Address</x:String>                      
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: you want to display the same information on both combobox?

Comment: no i want that once i select the first item of the first combobox want to show the second combobox

Comment: embed stack panels in  two different listbox and than you make it visible or hide it using   c# code on any event you like    lstEvents.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            prLoading.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.collapsed;

Comment: Smart Developer how can i make that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Form main, you can set the visibility of Second Combobox to be false, and then on the first combobox selection changed set it to true, Something like this

```
  public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        second_ComboBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void first_ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selecteditem = first_ComboBox.SelectedItem as string;
        if (selecteditem != null)
        {
            second_ComboBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

Comment: yeah its work but i also want to know how it works when the student information selected

Comment: @sahanYugantha Because it fires the selection changed event of the first combobox

Comment: cant we make the custom selections? to open different comboboxes

Comment: if you could give some hint or example how to do it

Answer (score 0):

on initialization make second combobox visiblity hidden

```
    public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    second_ComboBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private void first_ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
       first_ComboBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
```